# Mac Mini with two monitors (HDMI and DVI)

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, mac-mini

I've got Mac Mini connected to a LG Flatron IPS235t-bn monitor using Thunderbolt to DVI cable.
I want to purchase an HDMI monitor as a second for this system. Will this work if I just connect my new monitor to an HDMI port?

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine if you only need 1080p. Issues only start if you need 2k resolutions, as then you must use HDMI 1.4 throughout.